# Is it possible to change binding in the parent frame?

Tags: python, lexical-scope

I try to create closure where in parent frame exists binding with name **inner** which only can be accessibly using methods I provide by return. 
Here is my code:

```
def test():
    inner = 'value'
    def get_inner():
        return inner
    def set_inner(v):
        inner = v
    return get_inner, set_inner


get, set = test()

set('hello world')
```

But, when I actually call **set_inner()**  and in the body statement **inner = v** evaluated binding created in the local frame, but binding in the parent frame stays unchanged.

Here is how it looks:

[image]

as you can see new binding is created in the current frame of **set_inner** function, but I'd like to current the parent's binding.

I hope I made clear enough what I want to do.

Thank in advance.

**EDITED:**

Thank you to MartijnPieters, all I have to do is to place **nonlocal** statement:

```
def test():
    inner = 'value'
    def get_inner():
        return inner
    def set_inner(v):
        nonlocal inner
        inner = v
    return get_inner, set_inner
```

And now it changes binding in the parent frame

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or Python 3?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Python3

Comment: Then all you need is a `nonlocal inner` statement in the `set_inner()` function.

Comment: @MartijnPieters indeed, it works. Thank you for help :)